# sending text of selected list item from dropdown menu to controller from view in MVC4, but controller is receiving null value. Help me where m i wrong

Tags: jquery, html, json, asp.net-mvc-4

My view part of the code.

```
<div class="dropdown">
     <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button"id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Go To Class<span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
       @if (ViewBag.l != null)
       {
           foreach (var i in ViewBag.l)
           {
               <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="~/TProfile/selectClass">@i.CName</a></li>    
            }
        }
   </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown").on("click","a", function () {
            var value = $(this).text();
            $.getJSON("/TProfile/selectClass?val=" + value, function (result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    $(".header-line").html(value);
                }
                else {
                    alert("No Class found of selected item");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the Controller part....

```
public JsonResult selectClass(string val)
{        
    string value = val;
    MyDatabaseEntities8 db = new MyDatabaseEntities8();
    List<Class> c = db.Classes.Where(x => x.CName.Equals(value)).ToList();
    //string email = Session["LoggedEmailID"].ToString();
    //List<Class> clist = db.Classes.Where(x => x.TeacherEmail.Equals(email)).ToList();
    return this.Json(c[0],JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: You have not cancelled the default action of the link so you code will be hitting the method twice - change the links to `href="#"`. And use `$.getJSON('@Url.Action("selectClass", "TProfile")', { val: value }, function () {.....`

Comment: Thnx Stephen.. it is working now.. how foolish of me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `href="~/TProfile/selectClass"` to `href="#"` like Stephen suggested and it will work.What's happening is that the controller action defined in the anchor tag gets called before the jQuery click event and since you don't set the value parameter in the `href` the value will come through as null.

Comment: Thnx sir.. it is working now.. can this function be changed to $.ajax??

Comment: Please mark as answered if it helped you.You can change it to anything you want to although $ajax is slightly more complicated and requires setting a few different properties.Read this article for an example http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/